# How to set up a spark build.sbt file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I have been trying all day and cannot figure out how to make it work.

So I have a `common` library that will be my core lib for `spark`.

My `build.sbt` file is not working:

```
name := "CommonLib"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.5"

// addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")

// resolvers += "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
// resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
      "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.7.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
      //  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
      "org.apache.spark" % "spark-yarn_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
      "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.0"
)

//addSbtPlugin("org.spark-packages" % "sbt-spark-package" % "0.2.6")

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"

//libraryDependencies ++= {
//  val sparkVer = "2.1.0"
//  Seq(
//    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % "provided" withSources()
//  )
//}
```

All the commented out are all the test I've done and I don't know what to do anymore.

My goal is to have spark 2.3 to work and to have `scope` available too.

For my sbt version, I have `1.1.1` installed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had two main issues.

1. Spark is not compatible with scala 2.12 yet. So moving to 2.11.12 solved one issue
2. The second issue is that for intelliJ SBT console to reload the build.sbt you either need to kill and restart the console or use the `reload` command which I didnt know so I was not actually using the latest build.sbt file.

Comment: You can use IntelliJ Active Tool Window (shown as a toggle on the top left in latest versions), and open up SBT tool window.

From there, you can refresh your project as well

Comment: Yes, thats what I was doing but it was not reloading the edited `build.sbt` automatically.

Answer (score -2):

There's a Giter8 template that should work nicely:

https://github.com/holdenk/sparkProjectTemplate.g8